# Credit Card Expiration Date Selector WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, datetimepicker

Has anyone implemented a credit card expiration date selector in WP7 Mango? I've seen it done with WP7 Contrib prior to Mango (and was able to implement it on a non-mango project) however it doesn't seem to work right with the Mango SDK and the August Toolkit update.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could implement this? I'd use the normal datetimepicker however I don't need the "Day" selection, just the Month/Year. I know I can limit what's shown in the field after they select a date with the toolkit's datetimepicker, but I haven't found a way to hide the actual day picker.

Comment: What "doesn't seem to work right"? Rather than just ask someone else to provide a complete solution, let us help you fix the issue you are having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the `DatePicker` to exclude the date. [This](https://blogs.msdn.com/themes/blogs/generic/post.aspx?WeblogApp=delay&y=2010&m=09&d=21&WeblogPostName=there-are-lots-of-ways-to-ask-for-a-date-creating-custom-datepicker-timepicker-experiences-is-easy-with-the-windows-phone-toolkit&GroupKeys=) blog post explains how. Note that it was written pre-Mango so you might have to play with it a little bit to get it to work with the August 2011 toolkit release. But it should serve as a good starting point.

Comment: This is ultimately what I went with, albeit a tad different than what is described in that blog.